# VHDL tutorial for the Lattice ECP5 Versa Development Board

Tags: vhdl, lattice

I have got this Lattice ECP5 Versa Development Board and I am going to be working with it in the future. Right now I am looking for some good VHDL tutorial which will help me Play with the board and get confortable with before moving to the real Project I will be working on. Any good link is welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to VHDL, I can recommend a series of lectures on YouTube, they are not aimed specifically at your dev kit but should be a great help.
Here is a link to the first lecture "VHDL Lecture 1 VHDL Basics"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDq8-QDXmek

Comment: Links are bad because they go down and render answers useless, please provide relevant information in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the link Crispy. This dev kit is a bit different from the one i know maybe because it's mostly used for the PCI Express Project. Anyway thanks